# Change client data in database without refreshing page

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, cookies

I have a user system and I use cookies to make them automatically logout after 1 hour of inactivity, but only if the client refresh the page it would update the database row. This is my code so far:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $activeUser = $_SESSION['username'];
    if(isset($_COOKIE['active'])) {
        setcookie('active', $activeUser, time() +3600);
    } else {
        $makeOffline = $DB->query("UPDATE users SET user_loggedin = '0' WHERE user_id = '".$dbid."'");
        header("location: ".$site_url."/logout.php");
    }
}
```

What I'm asking now is if there's any way I could set `user_loggedin` to 0 after 1 hour of inactivity without that the client have to refresh the page?

Comment: Put this code in a seperate PHP if you didnt already, then call it with an ajax call, set a timer in the footer or header of your site and call the ajax function you have created for checking the cookie for example every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is :

1. store the active time into database.
2. update that active time once this user refreshes or does something.

so you can get if this user is still online or not based on the record + 1 hour.